# SwiftUI - Add a Navigation Bar Button on Condition

Tags: ios, conditional-statements, swiftui

Given i have a view like this..

```
@State var tabIndex: Int = 0
           
 var body: some View {

  TabView(selection: $tabIndex)
  {
   Text("Tab 1").tabItem({
    Image(systemName: "message")
   }).tag(0)           
                
   Text("Tab 2").tabItem({
    Image(systemName: "arkit")
   }).tag(1)             
          
   Text("Tab 3").tabItem({
    Image(systemName: "battery.100")
   }).tag(2)
  }.navigationBarTitle("Tabbed View")
            
 }
```

This produces a view like this which is what is expected:

[image]

to add a navigation button to the bar i can use

```
 .navigationBarItems(trailing:
  Button(action: {print("Button was tapped")}) {
   Image(systemName: "plus")
    .resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
  })
```

Which adds the button as [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFQlQ.png)

Is there any way to only add (or show) the button based on a condition?

```
if (self.tabIndex == 1){
  show button
}
else {
 don't show button
}
```

Comment: `TabView` embedded inside `NavigationView` isn't a good choice. Instead every tab in the `TabView` should have its own `NavigationView`. Like if there are three tabs, there should be three `NavigationView` if every tab needs their navigation hierarchy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: self.tabIndex == 1 ? 
    AnyView(self.trailingButton) : AnyView(EmptyView()))
```

somewhere below `body`

```
var trailingButton: some View {
  Button(action: {print("Button was tapped")}) {
   Image(systemName: "plus")
    .resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you don't just put the button on the relevant view under it's tab? Is there a reason it needs to be on the TabView?

Answer (score 21):

As `.navigationBarItems` will be deprecated in a future version of iOS it's better to use `.toolbar(_:)` View Modifier.

```swift
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        if tabIndex == 2 {
            // show button
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer

Comment: No need to use `AnyView` as well

Comment: navigationBarTrailing isn't defined for me

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use `AnyView`, you could also use `Group` or `Opacity` too.

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Group {
  if self.tabIndex == 1 {
    Button(action: {print("Button was tapped")}) {
     Image(systemName: "plus")
      .resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }
  }
})
```

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: 
    Button(action: {print("Button was tapped")}) {
     Image(systemName: "plus")
      .resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }.opacity(self.tabIndex == 1 ? 1 : 0)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has an accepted answer and I used it in my own solution but here's what I did:

```
var doneButton:AnyView {
    if !fromPreferences {
        return AnyView(Button(action: self.doneAction) {
            Text("Done")
        })
    }
    return AnyView(EmptyView())
}
```

and how I used it in the body:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: doneButton)
```

thanks @Asperi for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me, even when my condition was false which resulted in nothing being returned (the bar item correctly did not show, without errors). I find it a little cleaner than squeezing in a ternary operator.

```
.navigationBarItems(
    trailing: Button(
        action: {
            print("My Action")
        }
    ) {
        if myBool {
            Text("My Button")
        }
    }
)
```